# Download databasename.bak file

Tags: sql-server, backup, restore

I have downloaded databasename.bak file from my hosting company, when i tried to restore that DB file in SQL server 2008 it is keep on giving me following error.

The media family on device 'C:\go4sharepoint_1384_8481.bak' is incorrectly
formed. SQL Server cannot process this media family.
RESTORE HEADERONLY is terminating abnormally. (Microsoft SQL Server, Error:
3241)

According to this error and from following link
http://www.sqlcoffee.com/Troubleshooting047.htm

It is clear that either file i am downloading is corrupt or it is getting corrupted on the way?

Any idea, why I am keep on receiving this error?
I tried almost all ways but unable to fix this problem, please help me.

Comment: Did they give you a database BAK file, or an NT backup file?

Comment: yes, but it is created as a SQL Server backup, or an NT backup?

Comment: Asked later too: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3033265

Answer (score 0):

If you can, try to restore the backup in the same server/PC where that database backup was originally created. If it fails, it's clear that is not a communication issue (file corrupted because the FTP transfer) and something went wrong in the backup process.

If this works, you know the backup is not corrupted and the files becomes corrupt in the file transfer.

Comment: Thanks Markust for pointing light, let me try this and update you on this.

Comment: I just tried doing that It was running good on server.  So the problem is file gets corrupted because of FTP Transfer.  For file transfer I am using FTP - FileZila with TransferType as Binary, still it is giving problem, any idea?

Comment: I always I try to zip (using 7zip, Winzip or WinRar) the files whenever possible. Try to zip it and then do the transfer. Once you have the file, if you are unable to unzip it is because its corrupted again. At least this way you know in advance whether the file is valid or not. In FileZilla I use autodetect and works for me